# jQuery Dialog Load page with "wait" message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dialog

I have a button that opens a jQuery Dialog

```
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'Contract',
  height: 450,
  width:1100,
  modal:true,
  resizable: true
});



$( ".btnSend" ).click(function() {
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  $( "#dialog" ).load( "index.php?id="+id );
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'silver');
});
```

The `index.php` page loads very slowly so I would like to show a message before the page is completely loaded.

I try the classic loader script like

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

with proper CSS and HTML but this hide completely the dialog it seems that does not work well.

Do you have any idea/solution ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Show a Loading spinner or Message until it loads completely.

HTML

```
<span id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading..</span>
```

JavaScript

```
 $("#loading").show(); //Before loading the Data
      $( "#dialog" ).load( "index.php?id="+id, function(){

             $("#loading").hide(); //On Completion, hide it.
     }
);
```